# Returning last row in left outer join on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to query two tables.. I made example tables below:

```
---------------TABLE1 (t1)------------
| id  |type |    date    |
|  1  |  A  | 2018-01-01 |
|  2  |  C  | 2018-02-01 |
|  3  |  C  | 2018-03-01 |
|  4  |  C  | 2018-04-01 |
|  5  |  A  | 2018-01-01 |
|  6  |  C  | 2018-02-01 |
|  7  |  C  | 2018-03-01 |
|  8  |  B  | 2018-04-01 |

---------------TABLE2 (t2)------------
| id  |    date    |amount|  created   |
|  1  | 2018-01-01 |  100 | 2017-10-01 |
|  1  | 2018-01-01 |  700 | 2017-12-01 |
|  1  | 2018-03-01 |  300 | 2018-01-01 |
|  2  | 2018-02-01 |  500 | 2017-12-01 |
|  2  | 2018-02-01 |   50 | 2017-10-01 |
|  3  | 2018-03-01 |  750 | 2018-02-01 |
|  3  | 2018-03-01 | 1000 | 2018-03-01 |
|  4  | 2018-04-01 |  200 | 2018-03-01 |
|  5  | 2018-04-01 |  300 | 2018-02-01 |
```

I want the following:

```
---------------TABLE3------------
| id  |type |    date    |amount|  created   |
|  2  |  C  | 2018-02-01 |  500 | 2017-12-01 |
|  3  |  C  | 2018-03-01 | 1000 | 2018-03-01 |
|  4  |  C  | 2018-04-01 |  200 | 2018-03-01 |
|  6  |  C  | 2018-02-01 | NULL |    NULL    |
|  7  |  C  | 2018-03-01 | NULL |    NULL    |
```

I want a LEFT JOIN (I think in Postgres this is an outer join by default) on the conditions that `t1.id = t2.id`, `t1.date=t2.date`, and `t1.type = 'C'`.

I have the query done pretty easily, but am occasionally receiving multiple matches on `t2`. In this case, I want to only get the row from `t2` with the most recent `created` date.

In the end, I expect a table with the same number of rows as in:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE type = 'C'`

I checked multiple other questions on the site, but could not figure out how to do it with multiple conditions.

Comment: please show your current sql that is doing as you describe.  then I can modify it to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0282b4bf6ac700584106f745c11f7ca7)

You can first filter the t2 with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
    *
FROM
    t2
ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

After that you can join this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
   -- subquery here
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.date
```

`DISTINCT ON` gives out the first record of an ordered group. Here your group is the `id`. If you order the `id` groups by their date in descending order, you move the most recend record to the top.

Afterwards you can filter by `type` within the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Never knew about the `DISTINCT ON` function... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has a very nice extension called `distinct on`.  This makes it pretty simple to express your logic and to return one row per `id`:

```
select distinct on (t1.id), t1.*, t2.amount, t2.created
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date
where t1.type = 'C'
order by t1.id, t2.created desc
```